# EaselJS : .addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, addeventlistener, easeljs

I'm trying to use easelJS and there is something I can't understand.
Here it is : 
I have a MC containing all my buttons. Like this (PE and CO are my buttons. They have been initialized before in my code):

```
(lib.buttonsContainer = function() {
this.initialize();

// Layer 1
this.PE = new lib.PE();
this.PE.setTransform(121,163.3,2.382,2.382);

this.CO = new lib.CO();
this.CO.setTransform(135.2,59.9,2.382,2.382);

this.addChild(this.PE, this.CO);

//I give a name and an action
for(var childName in this){      
    if(this[childName] instanceof createjs.DisplayObject) {
        this[childName].name=childName;
        console.log(childName+" now has a name!!"); // it works.
        this[childName].addEventListener("click", function(evt) { alert(evt.target.parent.name); });
    }
}
}
```

The names are given as I expected, but firebug warns me  :

```
this[childName].addEventListener is not a function
```

and nothing is displayed.

As the names are given, I'm sure this[childName] is a displayObject, so I can't figure out why the addEventListener is not considered as a function.

Anyone ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, never mind. Flash export html file with a old version easelJS (easeljs-0.5.0.min.js). When I loaded the last version easeljs-0.8.0.min.js, my code started to work.

Sorry.
Thanks.